# PHP search integer and "0" and return result

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the code for my search, it work fine fine for me where it able to show result that i wanted.

Code that i have tried:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM PaymentDetails WHERE paymentAmount = $paymentAmount"
```

But is that possible to search "0" ? When i search 0 it will return blank error message. I wanted it to return a result instead of "error message"

The code that i given able are workable.

> Note: In my DB there is "0" in my column and i wanted to search "0"

Comment: Can you show us your query when you tried to find with 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get clear with 0 value first,

```
$paymentAmount = ($paymentAmount ?? 0); // php 7+
$paymentAmount = (!empty($paymentAmount) ? $paymentAmount : 0); // < php 7
```

then fire query

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM PaymentDetails WHERE paymentAmount = $paymentAmount";
```

But is that possible to search "0"? - **Yes**

Comment: `$paymentAmount = (!empty($paymentAmount) ? $paymentAmount : 0); // < php 7`  second method offcource also works in PHP 7, comment is meant for future readers as it looked like this didn't work on PHP 7 with that comment..

Comment: Why not cast it to int?